# Grails ElasticSearch mapping inherited domain classes

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, searchable

Say we have three Grails domain classes as follows:

```
class Person { 
  String name
  static searchable = true 
}

class Boss extends Person { }

class Employee extends Person { }
```

We then create/persist one Boss and one Employee instance:

```
def myBoss = new Boss(name:"Boss")
myBoss.save()
def myEmployee = new Employee(name:"Employee")
myEmployee.save()
```

By default, it seems the ElasticSearch plugin will index these instances as type `Boss` and `Employee`, not as type `Person`.

Given that only one inherited field will be searchable, is there any way to change the ElasticSearch mapping to `Person` rather than `Boss` and `Employee` (without using the low level API)?

This would allow us to use one query to search for all `Persons` by name, rather than two separate queries on `Boss` and `Employee`.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Is the inheritance is supported in indexing? I'm faced with the same problem now

Comment: No, I never managed to figure this one out. In the end I simply searched against both indices.